# How do I take user entered data from HTML forms in a JSP file, and enter it into a mysql database using a java class?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

So this is a project for my high school computer science class and my goal right now is to make a registration page, which stores its data inside a mysql server. So far, I've been able to connect to the database from java and also store data into it, but only when its been hardcoded by me.

I've searched the internet for solutions, and so far that has gotten me this code.

This is the main code in the jsp file.

```
<form action="NewAccount.jsp">
        <div class = "inputBox"> <p id = "inputFName">First Name</p>  <input type="text" name="FName"/> </div>
        <div class = "inputBox"> <p id = "inputLName">Last Name</p>  <input type="text" name="LName"/> </div>
        <div class = "inputBox"> <p id = "inputEmail">Email</p>  <input type="text" name="Email"/> </div>
        <div class = "inputBox"> <p id = "inputUser">Username</p>  <input type="text" name="User"/> </div>

        <div class = "inputBox"> <p id = "inputPass1">Password</p>  <input type="password" name="Pass1"/> </div> 
        <div class = "inputBox"> <p id = "inputPass2">Retype Password</p>  <input type="password" name="Pass2"/> </div>            

        <br/>

        <div id="inputButton"> <input type="submit" value="submit" name = "submit"/> </div>     
    </form>

    <%
        if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {

            CreateUser c = new CreateUser();

            String FName = request.getParameter("FName");
            String LName = request.getParameter("LName");
            String Email = request.getParameter("Email");
            String User = request.getParameter("User");
            String Pass = request.getParameter("Pass1");

            c.createUser(FName, LName, Email, User, Pass);
        }
    %>
```

This is the code in the Java class file.

```
private static PreparedStatement pst;

public void createUser(String FName, String LName, String Email, String User, String Pass) throws SQLException {
    SQLCon.Connect();

    pst = SQLCon.getMyConn().prepareStatement("insert into User_Info (FirstName,LastName,Email,Username,Password) values(?,?,?,?,?)");

    pst.setString(1, FName);
    pst.setString(2, LName);
    pst.setString(3, Email);
    pst.setString(4, User);
    pst.setString(5, Pass);
}
```

the SQLCon.Connect() method is below.

```
public static void Connect() throws SQLException {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/IA Schema";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "bruhbruh";

    try {
    //Connect to database
    myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println("failed");
    }
}
```

My project runs fine, but when I enter stuff data and click enter, the glassfish console thing says [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFV1t.png).

Any help on how to successfully enter the data into the database is greatly appreciated, but please keep in mind that this has all been self-taught from the internet (except java) and I may have a stupid mistake somewhere. Thank you.

The whole SQLCon class.

```java
package JavaClasses;

import java.sql.*;

public class SQLCon {

    private static Connection myConn;

    public static Connection getMyConn() {
        return myConn;
    }

    public static void Connect() throws SQLException {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/IA Schema";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "bruhbruh";

        try {
            //Connect to database
            myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println("failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is the NullPointerException pointing to?

Comment: It points to "pst = SQLCon.getMyConn().prepareStatement..." in the createUser() method.

Comment: is it possible getMyConn points to an object that hasn't been instantiated?

Comment: Can you post SQLCon class?

Comment: the only other thing in the SQLCon class is `private static Connection myConn;`   Is that the problem? There's also a getter for that.

Comment: Post the class. If myConn isn't being initialized then yes.

Comment: @ShreyGangwar You have a typo , in your `input` you have written `name=":Name"` ,i think this should be `name="LName"` , that the reason you are getting `Null` exception.

Comment: I posted the class @Jason

Comment: @Swati I fixed the typo but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Looks like you're constantly recreating the conncetion. In getMyConn() do something like if (myConn != null) return myConn; Also, run a simple test without glassfish to see if you can make a simple SELECT query to the myConn member after calling connect.

Comment: What should the else be for that?

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong name for LName in the jsp file.

```
    <div class = "inputBox"> <p id = "inputLName">Last Name</p>  <input type="text" name=":Name"/> </div>
```

LName, not :Name.

also in SQLCon class try the following changes.

```
   public static Connection getMyConn() {
       if(myConn!=null){
           return myConn;
       }else{
           SQLCon.Connect();
           return myConn;
       }
   }
```

Comment: the Connect() method is a void type, so I can't make myConn = to that.